# Click function on d3 force nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, force-layout

I am wondering how to set up a click function so that when you click on any one of the nodes (except for the nodes in the center of each group) it triggers a transition that causes an svg rectangle to appear by moving in from the left of the screen towards the right (I'd like to have it hidden initially). For some reason, nothing is registering when I click.

Also, does anyone know how I can pull in text from a json and append it onto the svg rectangle I have?

```
    var tooltip = svg.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 270)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("color", "black")
        .attr("opacity", 0.8);

svg.selectAll("node").on("click", function() {
    d3.select(tooltip)
        .transition()
        .attr("x", -300)
        .duration(450);
});
```

Here is the d3 code: http://plnkr.co/edit/nwmUN4RzAwam9dE5bCEj?p=preview

Comment: Note: I have the initial x value for the rectangle and the x value under the transition backwards for now, just so you can see where the svg rectangle would be displayed once you click on it.

Comment: Your example has many problems -- you're selecting the nodes incorrectly before they are being defined, you can't use a D3 selection with `d3.select()` (and don't need to), and you're overwriting the `click` handler with another, non-existent function.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the response. So do you know how to go about setting it up the correct way to get it working? Also, you mentioned there are many problems. Do you know what else there is apart from what you mentioned specifically?

Comment: Well you can make the rectangle move quite easily by putting the code in the right place: http://plnkr.co/edit/ACZb9ypKPZU8QFg0zSdT?p=preview

Comment: Ohhh okay, I see how it works now. Do you know if I have any more hoops or hurdles to think about if I'm trying to set up the click function so that it appends text from the node's corresponding json file to inside the rectangle? What I'm going for might make sense if you see the json file, which is here. https://api.myjson.com/bins/2424n

Comment: I suggest that you try doing this. There are lots of examples and questions about this.